# If Hinduism is not the same as Sanatana Dharma, in what way are they different?

Tags: history, terminology

That the names Hinduism was given by foreigners means nothing.  After all, "India" is a foreign-origin name.  Sanatana Dharma by definition extends back to the remotest past and would live forever.  Is Hinduism different in this regard?

Comment: In modern times, "Hinduism" is a geographical wrapper around *"SanAtana Dharma"*.

Comment: That makes no sense - Hindus are all over the world.

Answer (score 0):

Hinduism is an exonym, while Sanatana Dharma is an endonym. ([Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endonym_and_exonym)) Beyond that, there is no difference.